# Gradle equivelant for export checked off

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

What is the equivelant for export box unchecked for dependency?

what i currently have is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/tanab/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.3.1'

}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

but this is makes ABS be exported while compiling which causes Dex Errors which state that Android Support Lib has already been added.

I cant do this in the android studio dependency editor since any changes i make there will not go through when i run my app,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `android-library` plugin yet. But as you said you have dependency to support library added twice.

Normally I would run `gradle dependencies` to see all tree and after I would exclude transitive dependency to support library ([ref](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_exclude_transitive_dependency)):

```
dependencies {
   compile('com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.3.1') {
     //excluding a particular transitive dependency:
     exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
   }
 }
```